# Разглядеть ошибку в классе

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, объекты

Помогите отыскать ошибку в коде, пожалуйста. При его выполнении, я получаю ошибку TypeError: **init**() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given. Тысячу раз все перепроверил, но ничего не нашел(

```
import numpy as np
import random
np.random.seed(1)
class Neuro():
    def __init__(inpnode,hidnode,outnode,weights_1):
        # задать количество узлов во входном, скрытом и выходном слое 
        inode = inpnode
        hnode = hidnode
        sonode = outnode
        # коэффициент обучения 
        wei = weights_1

    #def trng():
    #def outp():
i_node=1   #int(input())
h_node=1    #int(input())
o_node=1    #int(input())
weights_2=0.3    #random.random()
print("---"+str(weights_2)+"---")
neuronetwork=Neuro(i_node,h_node,o_node,weights_2)
```

Comment: Для начала: у init по два подчеркивания с каждой стороны.

Comment: Что с ними не так? Не нужны? Я убирал - не помогало

Comment: С ними не так их количество. Нужно по два, а стоит по одному.

Comment: Понял, щас поправлю

Comment: Сделал, но все равно ошибка вылезает, теперь другая

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменить

```
def __init__(inpnode,hidnode,outnode,weights_1):
```

на

```
def __init__(self, inpnode,hidnode,outnode,weights_1):
```

И не забыть почитать про self, что это такое и зачем нужно

Comment: Не пойми неправильно - я сижу и пишу по книге, но зачем там self, объясняется плохо... Вот и убрал, не видя особой разницы) Большое спасибо

Comment: В python нет такой магической переменной, которая указывает на текущий инстанс класса. В python такой указатель передается первым аргаментом метода